# Is there a way to open pre-built Singularity container with files in my current directory?

Tags: docker, tensorflow, machine-learning, singularity-container

I am using a pre-built singularity container for Tensorflow ML in remote cluster.
I open the singularity container located in  `/cvmfs/unpacked.cern.ch/registry.hub.docker.com/fnallpc/`
with command as below

```
singularity run --nv --bind `readlink $HOME` --bind `readlink -f ${HOME}/nobackup/` 
--bind /cvmfs /cvmfs/unpacked.cern.ch/registry.hub.docker.com/fnallpc/fnallpc-docker:tensorflow-latest-devel-gpu-singularity
```

It opens the singularity image well and command works.

Now, I have several files that I need the Tensorflow environment, but when I open the image there is not file obviously. Is there a way that I can use the files in my working directory (which needs the Tensorflow environment) when I open the Singularity container? I wonder if there is a command to open the image and files in my working directory together, such that I have access to those files while being in the container image.

Comment: are you running the image locally or is it triggering a run on the remote cluster?

Comment: I am running the image locally

Answer (score 0):

Both your `$HOME` and the current directory are mounted automatically by default. However, auto mounts are allowed to fail silently if the path does not exist inside the container. *e.g.,* you execute from `/cluster/storage/somepath` but there is no `/cluster` inside the singularity container. The same can happen if `$HOME` is somewhere weird, but is much less common.

Explicit use of `--bind` does not have this problem. Adding `--bind "$PWD"` should take care of it.

You can quickly test that you're executing where you expect with `singularity exec --bind "$PWD" image.sif pwd`. The working directory inside the container matches the one outside the container (if available), falling back to `$HOME` if `$PWD` is not available, and `/` if neither `$PWD` nor `$HOME` are available inside the image.